# Загрузка страницы не прекращается

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем доброго времени суток. На одном из сайтов заметил, что не прекращается загрузка страницы(индикатор в заголовке вкладки не перестает вращаться). Выяснил, что причина - записи в iframe через document.write(). Код(упрощенно) примерно такой(зависание можно проверить локально):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>
    <body>

    <iframe id="k_c0"></iframe>

    <script language="JavaScript">
      var d;
      d=document.getElementById('k_c0').contentDocument;
      d.write('<div> 234</div>');
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Какие процессы вызывают крутящийся индикатор? И почему они возникают? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано в [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write)

> Метод document.write(str) работает только пока HTML-страница находится в процессе загрузки. Он дописывает текст в текущее место HTML ещё до того, как браузер построит из него DOM.

document.getElementById('k_c0').contentDocument - возвращает document. 
d.write - записывает в document фрейма и не может записать. Соответственно не может загрузить страницу полностью. Вот она и крутится.

Comment: Однако на том же ресурсе сказано:   Технически, вызвать document.write можно в любое время, однако, когда HTML загрузился, и браузер полностью построил DOM, документ становится «закрытым». Попытка дописать что-то в закрытый документ открывает его заново. При этом все текущее содержимое удаляется. Следовательно, почему тогда содержимое фрейма не перезаписывается?

Comment: потому что с точки зрения безопасности к фрейму нельзя обратится из другого url

Comment: Точне не так, в Вашем случае записывать можете, но остальную часть документа он обрабатывать не будет. Вы должны писать `d.body.innerHTML ="<div>111</div>"`

Comment: Если интересно, ссылка на сайт: [ссылка](http://www.topnews.ru/news_id_101265.html)

Comment: а у меня он загрузился нормально кстати

Comment: лоадера нет, а соответственно страница загрузилась

Comment: И небольшое замечание вёрстке: надо бы по центру сделать. http://prntscr.com/enxn7l

Comment: Отключил фаервол(ksp) и !!!Сайт загрузился нормально! Видимо фаервол нарушал работу рекламных скриптов, что приводило к ситуации, описанной в вопросе.